# jupyter notebook import error: no module named 'matplotlib'

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I'm an ubuntu 16.4 user and I installed anaconda3 and using both python2 and python3 kernels.

> >>>jupyter kernelspec list
> Available kernels:
> python2    /home/peterkim/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/python2
> python3    /home/peterkim/anaconda3/share/jupyter/kernels/python3

and.. the problem was that I don't know where/how to install packages in order to for my python2 jupyter notebook not to make error 'no module named ...'.
I tried `pip install matplotlib` and `conda install matplotlib` and I also appended '/home//anaconda2/pkgs' to the `sys.path`.

(I also installed anaconda2 in search of the way of using parallel kernels. After I realised that anaconda2 was not needed. but I didn't uninstall it.)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: first of all, I would got for one python Version. Preferably the Python3 Version. Uninstall Conda with `conda install anaconda-clean`and re-install

Comment: @Confidence it worked for me. Thumbs Up.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd recommend reading through here:

https://conda.io/docs/py2or3.html

I had the same problem after installing a Python 2.7 environment inside my Anaconda3 installation. I'm not sure which command I used to create the environment, but it actually didn't install all the optional packages that are usually bundled with Anaconda (like matplotlib, numpy, ...). But that's not a big issue, you can easily install additional packages with pip as follows:

First, list your conda environments:

```
C:\Users\Felix>conda info --envs
# conda environments:
#
ipykernel_py2            D:\Anaconda\envs\ipykernel_py2
root                  *  D:\Anaconda
```

Next, activate your python 2 environment using `source activate <env>` (Linux/OSX) or `activate <env>` (Windows):

```
C:\Users\Felix>activate ipykernel_py2

(ipykernel_py2) C:\Users\Felix>
```

Finally, use pip to install the required packages:

```
(ipykernel_py2) C:\Users\Felix>pip install matplotlib
Collecting matplotlib
...
Successfully installed matplotlib-2.0.0
```

Hope that this helps.

Comment: I followed this exactly, but did not resolve my issue. I verified my pacakge is installed  "(env) pipi list". Jupyter notebook executed from same env, but still same error.

Answer (score 16):

When using python3 version of jupyter (`pip3 install jupyter`), matplotlib has to be installed using pip3: `pip3 install matplotlib`

Answer (score 5):

For those still looking for a solution, especially using virtualenv, this worked for me:

1 - Inside your project directory, create a virtual environment. You may have to install `virtualenv` in case you don't have it

```
virtualenv myenv --python=python3.7
```

2 - Install `matplotlib` inside of your virtual env:

```
pip3 install matplotlib
```

3 - Install `ipykernel` inside your virtual env

```
pip3 install ipykernel
```

4 - Connect your jupyter kernel to your new environment. You may have to use sudo here

```
python3 -m ipykernel install --name=myenv
```

5 - When you start your `jupyter lab`, you will have the option to select your env, which has matplotlib installed

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got around it with typing the following command in the terminal:

`conda install matplotlib`

This will download the matplotlib package into your anaconda directory.

Comment: using python 3.7, installed anaconda3. I can see all packages in my anaconda directory/pkgs. What else I am supposed to do. Do I have to do any pip install inside my jupyter notebook for matplotlib. Or setup env etc (how?)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on my windows 10 :

1. I didn't use conda. I simply downloaded python 3.x version, then
   created a python 3 environment by the following command :
   `c:\python3x\python -m venv c:\path\to\your\env`.
2. After that you can
   check your python version by this command `python -v`.
3. Then you need to activate the python 3 environment by entering this command :
   `env/Scripts/activate`.
4. Then install the matplotlib library by doing 
   `pip3 install matplotlib` .

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the version of python executable and the path from where the library is getting used:

import sys

sys.executable    # to know the version of executable used

sys.path          # to know from which path library is getting imported.

And then:
I have installed the library in jupyter notebook cell by using pip.

pip install matplotlib

After that import started working for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the matplotlib conda pkg was corrupted.

```
conda list
```

First, identify all the matplotlib pkgs installed in your environment. In my case, there were 2 pkgs.

> matplotlib
>
> matplotlib-base

Now remove those using conda.

```
conda remove matplotlib
conda remove matplotlib-base
```

Now check the list again to make sure, all the pkgs removed successfully.
Then reinstall them again.

```
conda install matplotlib
conda install matplotlib-base
```

You may encounter an error saying

```
SafetyError: The package for matplotlib-base located at /home/<yourusername>/anaconda3/pkgs/matplotlib-base-3.1.3-py37hef1b27d_0 appears to be corrupted. The path 'lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib-3.1.3-py3.7-nspkg.pth' has an incorrect size. reported size: 569 bytes actual size: 570 bytes
```

Now you need to remove this corrupted folder, in my case, "matplotlib-base-3.1.3-py37hef1b27d_0".

Then try installing the pkgs again. It's better to run

```
conda remove matplotlab
```

again before reinstalling,  to make sure anything left of those pkgs completely wiped out.

Answer (score 0):

In windows OS, I found @melkorCba suggestion helpful. But, I have some edits:

1. After you type `conda list` in conda console, you can see matplotlib listed. Do not uninstall the module yet.
2. Go to conda GUI, launch Jupyter, clear Kernel and run the notebook again. To clear Kernel, in the Jupyter notebook, go to kernel tab > Restart and Clear Output.