# jupyter notebook python on MAC os : “no module named Orange”

Tags: python, orange

I've installed orange ，when I test in terminal, I can see it run perfectly ,but when I input "import Orange" in jupyter notebook, it turns back “no module named Orange”

[image]

[image]

Comment: sounds like a path/environment issue: make sure jupyter knows where to look for the module.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jupyter notebook import error: no module named 'matplotlib'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43437884/jupyter-notebook-import-error-no-module-named-matplotlib)

Comment: you need to install it ? .. go to command promt and type pip install Orange

Comment: @thomas that doesn't help install it into the Jupyter kernel

Answer (score 1):

In your notebook,

```
import orange
```

should be

```
import Orange
```

Comment: No，big one isn't

Comment: If you use `Orange.data.Table()` later on, it sure is. This is how Python identifiers and namespaces work. :D

Comment: @YingyingYu Please have a look at the import statement inside red box in the screenshot posted by you.